# Folder structure to json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am trying to take a folder structure and turn it into a JSON with this type of format:

```
.
├── Folder
│   ├── Image.png
│   └── Image_1.png
└── Folder2
    ├── Image.png
    └── Image_1.png
```

With a structure like this:

```
{
  "Folder": ["Image.png", "Image_1.png"],
  "Folder2": ["Image.png", "Image_1.png"]
}
```

Thanks. Is something like this possible?

Edit: This is what I have started with but the recursion is breaking when trying to drill down into folders within folders

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

var structure = {};

function findFiles(folder) {
    fs.readdir(folder, (err, files) => {
        files.forEach(file => {
            console.log(file);
            if(fs.lstatSync(__dirname + "/" + file).isDirectory()){
                console.log(folder)
                findFiles(folder + "/" + file);
            }
        });
    })
}

findFiles(__dirname)
```

Comment: It is possible.  Maybe take a crack at it first?  Start with the 'fs' library.  Nice chance to use your recursion skills.

Comment: Well I'm a little stumped. I tried using fs.readdir, but not sure how to tell if it's a file or folder, and then how to know when to stop going deep down a path.

Comment: @Jeff peruse the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), and give it a try. Then post your attempt and what, specifically, does not work about it.

Comment: Well I have been going through it and getting stuck trying to find folders within folders. I added some code of where I am at.

Comment: See my recent answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52939775/4632627

Comment: How do you want nested folders to be represented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem. Here's my solution, using sync functions. The output JSON will contain an array of objects that can be either strings (for file names) or objects (for directories).

Code ([live](https://repl.it/@mihaifm/dirToJSON)):

```
var fs = require('fs'), path = require('path'), util = require('util');

var dirToJSON = function(dir, done) {
  var results = [];

  function recWalk(d, res) {
    var list = fs.readdirSync(d);
    list.forEach((name) => {
      var tempResults = [];
      var file = path.resolve(d, name);
      var stat = fs.statSync(file);
      if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
        recWalk(file, tempResults);
        var obj = {};
        obj[name] = tempResults;
        res.push(obj);
      } else {
        res.push(name);
      }
    });
  }

  try {
    recWalk(dir, results);
    done(null, results);
  } catch(err) {
    done(err);
  }
};

dirToJSON("/home/", function(err, results) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(util.inspect(results, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));
});
```

Output:

```
[ { node: [ '.bash_logout', '.bashrc', '.profile' ] },
  { runner: 
     [ '.bash_logout',
       '.bashrc',
       '.profile',
       'config.json',
       'index.js',
       { node_modules: [] },
       'test.js' ] } ]
```

Note that I'm printing results with `util.inspect` to allow infinite depth for objects, but you can also do `JSON.stringify(results)`

Comment: This is really really interesting. Is node modules empty, because there's nothing in it?

Comment: @Jeff yes, empty folder corresponds to empty array